# Memory piling up with every page reload - source files loaded multiple times into memory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed that my app gets slower with every page reload so started to look for a leak.
Interestingly, heap doesn't get cleared on page reload rather than doubling in size (chrome) even while using click + hold for "clear cache and hard reset", than noticed the source: `bundle.js` (done by rollup) which appears multiple times in memory after each reload:

[image]

How's that possible? Rechecked `index.html` its loaded a single time, so I don't understand.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of livereload are you using? https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload 0.6.3+ has a fix for memory issues

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm using `^0.7.0` so I guess that should be fine and it happens in production as well without it.

Comment: Well crap, I just found out I have the same issue with my own website between reloads. I'm looking into it now

Comment: Jeez, that's strange! Is it pure vanilla/react/lit-element?

Comment: No vanilla/lit-element, but it is react, and my bundle.js is persisted between page refreshes just like yours. I can see I have 5 bundle.js's sitting in memory

Comment: @abelito will keep looking for a clue and will post if anything comes up, eventually let me know if you found something too.

Comment: I'm still working through this, but I've found that there may be multiple reasons this is happening. When I gutted my application (blank js file), it fixed it. After adding in a boiler plate React imports + rendering + my hot module replacement plugin, it started to appear again. So I removed all the hot module (HMR) stuff -- hotOnly: true + plugins line in webpack and that fixed it. Started adding in MY code without HMR and the issue came back so unfortunately it may be a slog for you to find the reasons as well. I'll update if I find an easy way to troubleshoot it too

Comment: hmm, tried to disable every extension and incognito window as well, I guess this gonna be still our source's issue.

Comment: @abelito do you experience the memory issue as well or only the multiple src in memory?

Comment: @abelito Did you ever find out what was causing it?

Comment: @SébastienTromp I checked my commits for this website and they stopped on May 5th unfortunately -- my original code edits to check what I mentioned above are still there. I did not find out why it was being caused, but I assumed it was either my own code or the react library. Since the website was really straightforward, I recreated the website from scratch to using some simpler libraries (handlebars, re-used my DB code, etc) and haven't run into the issue again.