# Imported scripts not cleaned up from memory when Angular application is destroyed

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I have an Angular application, and have noticed that when the page is closed (and application is destroyed) some script imports linger in memory. This is for instance what the Chrome's memory profiler tells me after I opened and closed my application twice since the last memory snapshot:

[image: memory snapshot]

As you can see, there are a couple of `vendor.js` elements in `(compiled code)` that are not accessible to the GC (distance is `-`).

Something that I found is that, if I manually remove the `vendor.js` script tag (i.e. I open the Elements tab in the dev tools, then hit Del to remove the script tag), then close the app, there is no memory leak anymore.
However, if I try to remove the script tag from the console (using for instance `document.body.getElementsByTagName('script')[1].remove()` which targets the correct script), I get a memory snapshot diff looking like the following:

[image]

[image]

So I guess my questions are:

1. What is happening here? Why are the scripts not properly cleaned up when closing the window?
2. Why is there a difference between manually removing the DOM script node in the dev tools vs doing it via javascript?
3. Is there a solution?

I didn't find much on the web. I came across these:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17637#issuecomment-387801113, but the solution proposed didn't do anything
- as well as the things suggested there: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17637#issuecomment-351094525

Comment: Similar question (but without any answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291225/memory-piling-up-with-every-page-reload-source-files-loaded-multiple-times-int

Comment: Both your question and the one Sébastien linked only mention Chrome. Please follow the same process with FireFox and report the findings.

Comment: My use case is actually specific to Chrome - I'm building an app on a platform that uses a Chrome browser as a loader, so I can't easily run my app in another browser.

Comment: Great - Can you check in on FF please? That will allow you to validate that this is a Chrome only issue. Then, you can address it with them.